# Convert data frame to matrix using pandas

Tags: pandas, dataframe, matrix

I am new to pandas. I have following data frame

```
Column1  Column2    Number
abcd1234  1234abcd   7
8yghc123  09mjko][   5
```

So `Column1` and `Column2` represent 8-character strings and `Number`  column has integers.

Now,  I want to convert this in a matrix `Mij` where `i` represents each unique values in `Column1` and `j` represents each unique value in `Column2`. So, for example if `abcd1234=I=0` and `1234abcd=j=0`, then  `M[0,0]=7`

(I want the matrix representation for use in analytics.)

Comment: Please explain how we're supposed to know `abcd1234=I=0` and `1234abcd=j=0`? Where are those coming from? Is there some other dataframe or dict to translate those values?

Comment: This is  duplicate of [**Create Pandas DataFrame from (row, column, value) data**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44161912/create-pandas-dataframe-from-row-column-value-data). Your only twist is figuring out how to convert your 8-character string representation into coordinates - based on something you haven't told us about. Also, convert the final df to matrix with `df.as_matrix(...)`

Comment: I am a novice and learning so, my apologies for not being clear. Part of the implicit confusion is the fact that I have no idea how to convert these 8-character strings into coordinates. smci's comment seems to suggest that about the use of dict to translate, can you please help how to use dict or another dataframe.

Comment: I'm not criticizing, just trying to help. There must be something extra missing that helps you translate 8-character strings like `abcd1234=I=0`, we can't possibly know what is. Otherwise how do you know that it isn't 1,2 or any other random integer? Where did that dataframe come from, did someone else generate it? Ask them for an explanation.

Comment: Thanks. Dataframe is given to me by my instructor, and we are told that it represents random samples. We are free to use any indexing as long as we can represent the data frame in matrix format.

Comment: I think the help I need is to translate strings to numbers. I am not able to do that.

Comment: Dude, noone is able to help you decrypt those strings into numbers. There must be something missing, you have to ask whoever generated them or wherever they came from. Don't ask us. Look at the other data-structures, functions, data dictionary in your environment.